# How can I capture checkbox toggles in a custom data type?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable, event

I'm using a custom data type to provide an interactive checkbox within a lightning datatable.

Here's the component's JS:

```javascript
import checkbox from './checkbox.html';

export default class CoreDatatable extends LightningDatatable {
    ...
    static customTypes = {
        progressBar: {
            template: progressBar,
            standardCellLayout: false,
            typeAttributes: ['value']
        },
        checkbox: {
            template: checkbox,
            standardCellLayout: false,
            typeAttributes: ['value']
        }
    };
    ...
    handleCheckboxToggle(event) {
        console.log('handleCheckboxToggle);
    }
}
```

`checkbox.html`:

```html
<template>
    <lightning-input
        class="slds-p-left_medium"
        type="checkbox"
        checked={typeAttributes.value}
        onchange={handleCheckboxToggle}
    ></lightning-input>
</template>
```

I'm able to send default data to the checkboxes (i.e., get them to be checked when the page loads), but clicking the checkbox, while successfully toggling the value, doesn't call the handler, but rather fires an error:

[image: Error dialog]

Now, I've seen this error before, and believe it means it can't find the handler named in the attributes, so where should I put it? I tried putting it in a `checkbox.js` with no change.

Answer (score 1):

Your handler function name and one specified in HTML does not match. Looks like a simple typo

May be stick with `handleCheckboxChange` as the function name instead of `handleCheckboxToggle`.

```
...
handleCheckboxChange(event) {
    console.log('handleCheckboxToggle);
}
```

Comment: I wish that were the case. In the code they're both called `handleCheckboxToggle`, and I still get the error. The typo was a case of me in one place typing in the text and in another pasting.

Comment: @Chuck Can you share some more code or may be an open source where I can deploy this LWC Component and reproduce the exact error?

Comment: It's currently a private repository, but I'll try to create a project that reduces the problem to only the required code.

Answer (score 0):

Your console.log contains an unclosed string:

`console.log('handleCheckboxToggle);`

Should be:

`console.log('handleCheckboxToggle');`